# how to assign value inside ternery operator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to assign value to variable inside ternary operator.

This is my code :

```
let myData;

{
    data ? myData = _.findLastIndex(users, function(o) { return o.user == 'pebbles';}) : ''
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What it is not working ?

Comment: it should be `myData = data ? _.find.. : ''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you for some reason need the empty string in case `data` is falsy, a ternary is indeed the shortest way to do so:

Remove the `{}`, and move the assignment out of the ternary statement:

```
let myData = data ? _.findLastIndex(users, function(o) { return o.user == 'pebbles';}) : '';
```

Or, (in my opinion) more readable:

```
let myData = data ?
    _.findLastIndex(users, function(o) {
        return o.user == 'pebbles';
    }) :
    '';
```

If you don't need the empty string, use an `if`, as [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43489284/1835379).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any useful "else" clause, don't use a ternary operator; use a good old `if`:

```
if (data) {
    myData = _.findLastIndex(users, function(o) { return o.user == 'pebbles';});
}
```

You can even inline that if you insist on doing a one-liner (though it's not great for readability):

```
if (data) myData = ...;
```

Comment: I'd add a ternary example. The "empty string" else clause might be necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I refuse to write nonsensical code. :) This is begging for an `if`, not for shoehorning a ternary in somehow.

Answer (score -3):

You can wrap statement inside `()` and make it an expression.

```js
var data = null;
var a = "foo";
data? (a= "null string") : (a = "")

console.log(a)
```

As pointed out in comments, this approach is a bad practice. The reason for this would be that `false` state would return `""` but its not assigned to anything. This would be difficult to understand for anyone else.

**Correct Way** is to use an `if`

```js
var data = null;
var a = "foo";
if(data)
  a = "Null string";

console.log(a)
```

Comment: `var a = data === null ? 'null string' : '';` would be much more sensible.

Comment: @deceze Objective of question is to see how we can assign value in a ternary operator. Also you are missing the point that if `data` is not null, `a` is not updated

Comment: `var a = "foo";` is pointless. This just isn't how you assign a value in a ternary statement. deceze's example is correct.

Comment: But `a` *is* going to be updated either way in your code.

Comment: @Cerbrus if you want to override in only one condition, you can try something like this. Yes `if` is more suited, but this is also a way to assign variable inside ternary operator

Comment: @Rajesh: There are 100 ways to conditionally set a variable. About 98 of those ways are ridiculous. Just because "it works", doesn't mean it's good.

Comment: @deceze Have updated my answer specifying the possible reason for this approach being bad. Also keeping this answer as this is a bad way, but might come in handy in some rare case. Also the discussion in comments would help. So, if there is any inconsistencies, please point it out. `:-)`

Comment: `if(data === null)` is not the same as `data ?`. Not even close.